# How do I nest the sub-categories right under the parent category during render

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want the sub-categories of each of my category objects rendered as a drop-down menu nested inside it's parent category.
I am having a hard time implementing that. How does it work?

This is my Category and SubCategory Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my view function:

```py
def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    #sub_categories = I don't know how
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        #'sub_categories': sub_categories
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

This is inside my template:

```html
{% for category in categories %}
    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="py-3 nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ category.name }}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu rounded-0">

            {% for sub_category in sub_categories %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                {{ sub_category.name }}
            </a>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The categories are rendering fine, my problem is with the sub-categories.

Comment: What is the problem with the sub-categories?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub_categories model needs to be somehow linked to the Categories Model.
You should have something like this inside your sub_categories model:

```
class Sub_categories(models.Model):    
    category = models.OneToOneField(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

You can do this on your views.py:

```
def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

And in your template you can do this:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="py-3 nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ category.name }}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu rounded-0">

            {% for sub_category in category.sub_categories.all %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                {{ sub_category.name }}
            </a>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I assume you could also use one ManyToManyField inside your Category model to make the category model related to the sub_category one.

Answer (score 0):

This method does not require any changes to your models.

What I have had to do in cases like this is put categories and subcategories together in a single data structure and then just pass that entire thing to the template.

Here is some code for another project I have done. I was pairing a study with its list of participants.

**views.py**

```
        participants = []
        try:
            studies = Study.objects.filter(investigators=Researcher.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id))
        except (Study.DoesNotExist, Researcher.DoesNotExist) as e:
            studies = []
        participantList = []
        for study in studies:
                participantList = Approval.objects.filter(study=study)
                if (len(participantList) == 0 ):
                    participants.append([[], study])
                elif (len(participantList) == 1 ):
                    participants.append([participantList, study])
    return render(request, 'manage.html',{'studies':participants, 'profile': user_profile})
```

**template.html**

```
{% for participants, study in studies %}
    {{study.title}}
            {% for part in participants %}
                <p>{{part.info}}</p>

                {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The key is essentially in pairing the required information together in a list and then iterating them together in the template to avoid the for loop problem.

As you are not pairing models with models, you can just replace the `participantList = Approval.objects.filter(study=study)` and all that with a call to a dict with the main category name as an argument.

Comment: Please be kind and check my updated question, look at how I modeled my Category and SubCategory

Answer (score 0):

In order to create subcategory models...

```
Category(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()

Sub_Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    category = models.ManyTOManyField(Sub_Category)

def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')

    cid = #Generate your Category id single or list...

    //you can ever it multiple time with for loop...
    sub_categories = Sub_Category.objects.filter(category=cid) 
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'sub_categories': sub_categories
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```